# How can I do a breadth-first search in SQL?

Tags: sql, tree

Given a tree stored as a relation:

```
++++++++++++++++++
| Parent | Child |
++++++++++++++++++
|   1    |   2   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   1    |   3   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   3    |   4   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   3    |   5   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   2    |   6   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   7    |   8   |
++++++++++++++++++
|   7    |   9   |
++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I get all the descendants of a given node?  For example, for
1, I want (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and for 3 I want (3, 4, 5), and for 7 I
want (7, 8, 9).

I'm doing this from a script (Python, but that doesn't matter) so I
can do something like:

```
children(p):
   nodes = SELECT child FROM relation WHERE parent=p
   for each node in nodes
        nodes += children(node)
   return nodes

nodes = children(root)
```

But if there's some funky SQL that lets me do that in one query, that
would be awesome.

Comment: How deep can the tree be? Recursive CTEs (SQL 2005 and up) are a good bet, but they have a fairly limited recursion depth.

Comment: You probably should specify what RDBMS, too.

Comment: @Philip Kelley: What is meant by 'limited'? The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) states that the default is 100, but you could explicitly specify, for example, 0, which means unlimited depth of recursion.

Comment: @phillip: I suppose in general the tree could be any depth.  In my case I doubt it would be more than a dozen levels deep.

Comment: @JNK: I'm using PostgreSQL but if there's something generic, I'd prefer it.

Comment: In SQL Server, you'd use "Common Table Expressions". They were added in SQL 2005, and can hardly be said to be an industry-wide standard. If Postgres has some form of recursive query code or mechanism, use that, otherwise you'll have to write a conventional recursive looping structure.

Comment: @Phillip Kelly - PostgresSQL also supports CTEs (which are part of one of the ANSI SQL standards - 2003 I think) - http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme

Comment: Can SQL server use a SEARCH BREADTH FIRST By... to search through a table with a with clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ability to change the table definition then using a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) rather than a direct parent link makes this problem much easier to solve. Joe Celko's [SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605762) covers this in some detail.

Comment: I'd prefer not to mess with my schema right now and I have adequate performance using the query I posted below but this is brilliant.  Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive WITH. I did it using Oracle 12c. The syntax might differ a little bit with another DBMS. I built the table and populated it with its data with the following script :

```
create table parent_child (
  parent integer,
  child integer,
  constraint parent_child_pk primary key (parent, child)
);

insert all
  into parent_child values (1, 2)
  into parent_child values (1, 3)
  into parent_child values (3, 4)
  into parent_child values (3, 5)
  into parent_child values (2, 6)
  into parent_child values (7, 8)
  into parent_child values (7, 9)
  select 1 from dual;

commit;
```

Then I use a recursive WITH :

```
with descendants (node) as (
  select 1 from dual -- root
  union all
  select child from descendants inner join parent_child on parent = node
)
select node from descendants order by node;
```

`select 1 from dual` is the anchor member (base case of recursion). It puts a 1 in the `descendants` table. You can use 3 or 7 instead just like in your example. Then comes the recursive case with the `select child from descendants inner join parent_child on parent = node` recursive member. It means that we take the new nodes in descendants (that means 1) and get all their children (that means 2 and 3) and add them to the `descendants` table. So, now we have 1, 2 and 3 in the table. We start again using 2 and 3 as new nodes and get their children which are 4 and 5. Next we have the full result which is probably what you want.

We can use `listagg` if we need a string but then we need a way to order things or at least a way to identify the root node. Note that it is not a good idea to flatten the tuples in the table as one big string.

```
with descendants (node, is_root) as (
  select 1, 'Y' from dual -- root
  union all
  select child, 'N' from descendants inner join parent_child on parent = node
)
select '(' || listagg(node, ', ') within group (order by case is_root when 'Y' then 0 else 1 end, node) || ')' list
from descendants;
```

which gives `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Comment: This is fantastic. Your query syntax works in SQLite, and it looks like it should work in Postgres and MySQL 8+ as well. I just had to use `with recursive descendants`. The Postgres documentation has a great explanation of this pattern: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

```
children(p):
   nodes = SELECT child FROM relation WHERE parent=p
   for each node in nodes
        sql = SELECT child FROM relation WHERE parent=node
.
.
.
        nodes += children(node)
   return nodes

nodes = children(root)
```

OR

do two functions, something like:

has children(p)

get children array(p)

Comment: I can turn recursion into a loop myself. ;-)

Comment: @jnk: Yes, I'm looking for an SQL technique.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with:

```
# Parents is a list of strings
def _children(parents):
    if len(parents) == 0:
        return []

    db = self.env.get_db_cnx()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT t.id "
                   "FROM ticket AS t "
                   "LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_custom AS p ON "
                   "    (t.id=p.ticket AND p.name='%s') "
                   "WHERE p.value IN (%s)" % 
                   (self.fields['parent'],
                    "'" + "','".join(parents) + "'"))
    children = ['%s'%row[0] for row in cursor] 
    return parents + _children(children)
```

Though I think that the name of the function is a little weak.  I may change it to _tree or something.

This works in Trac 0.11 with PostgreSQL 8(?).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed example: [Hierarchical Span of Control report in SQL, without Oracle CONNECT BY syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878064/hierarchical-span-of-control-report-in-sql-without-oracle-connect-by-syntax/53878410). To get the descendants (or in my example, the indirect reports), you first need to *flatten* the tree into a path.