# Hierarchical Span of Control report in SQL, without Oracle CONNECT BY syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, ansi-sql

**Summary**

Span of Control is a count of how many employees report to a given manager. Direct and indirect report counts should be split into their own totals.
Other counts are needed, including many vacancies for direct and indirect reports there are in the organisation. A manager is any position that has other positions reporting to it.
The reporting path from the top to anywhere in the tree is required to *flatten* the structure.

I've seen this problem appear often in HR reporting and data warehouse projects. I have only been able to solve it in Oracle.
Can this report be written in (ANSI) SQL that is compatible with another database, such as SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

**Detail**

Visual representation of an organisation hierarchy:

```
Level 1                                1:3
                                        |
                        ----------------+-----------------------------------
                        |               |               |                  |
Level 2                2:1            13:             10:12               4:2
                        |                               |
               ---------+----------           ----------+----------
               |        |         |           |         |         |
Level 3      12:10     3:        3:         5:10-1    11:11      6:
               |                              |                   |
            ---+---               ------------+------------       |
            |     |               |     |     |     |     |       |
Level 4    7:4   7:9             8:5   8:7   8:6   8:    8:      9:8
```

Each node or leaf of the tree is represented by one of the following:

- `position_id:employee_id`
- `position_id:employee_id-multi_job_sequence` (if `multi_job_sequence>0`)
- `position_id:` (vacant)

**Expected output**

```
POSITION_ID    POSITION_DESCR         REPORTSTO_POSITION_ID      EMPLOYEE_ID    MULTI_JOB_SEQUENCE      EMPLOYEE_NAME      TREE_LEVEL_NUM      IS_MANAGER     MAX_INCUMBENTS       FILLED_HEAD_COUNT      VACANT_HEAD_COUNT     FILLED_DIRECT_REPORTS     VACANT_DIRECT_REPORTS       FILLED_INDIRECT_REPORTS     VACANT_INDIRECT_REPORTS       EMPLOYEES_UNDER_POSITION        VACANCIES_UNDER_POSITION       REPORTING_PATH_POSITION_ID     REPORTING_PATH_POSITION_DESCR                       REPORTING_PATH_EMPLOYEE        REPORTING_PATH_EMPLOYEE_NAME
1              CEO                    NULL                       3              0                       Jill               1                   1              1                    1                      0                     3                         1                           9                           5                             12                              6                              1                              CEO                                                 3                              Jill
2              Senior Manager         1                          1              0                       Tom                2                   1              1                    1                      0                     1                         2                           2                           0                             3                               2                              1>2                            CEO>Senior Manager                                  3>1                            Jill>Tom
3              West Winger            2                          NULL           NULL                    NULL               3                   0              2                    0                      2                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>2>3                          CEO>Senior Manager>West Winger                      3>1>(vacant)                   Jill>Tom>(vacant)
4              Executive Assistant    1                          2              0                       Doug               2                   0              1                    1                      0                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>4                            CEO>Executive Assistant                             3>2                            Jill>Doug
5              Supervisor South       10                         10             1                       Frank              3                   1              1                    1                      0                     3                         2                           0                           0                             3                               2                              1>10>5                         CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South                 3>12>10-1                      Jill>Fred>Frank
6              Supervisor East        10                         NULL           NULL                    NULL               3                   1              1                    0                      1                     1                         0                           0                           0                             1                               0                              1>10>6                         CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor East                  3>12>(vacant)                  Jill>Fred>(vacant)
7              Expert                 12                         4              0                       Olivia             4                   0              2                    2                      0                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>2>12>7                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor West>Expert           3>1>10>4                       Jill>Tom>Frank>Olivia
7              Expert                 12                         9              0                       David              4                   0              2                    2                      0                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>2>12>7                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor West>Expert           3>1>10>9                       Jill>Tom>Frank>David
8              Minion                 5                          5              0                       Carol              4                   0              5                    3                      2                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>10>5>8                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South>Minion          3>12>10-1>5                    Jill>Fred>Frank>Carol
8              Minion                 5                          6              0                       Mary               4                   0              5                    3                      2                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>10>5>8                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South>Minion          3>12>10-1>6                    Jill>Fred>Frank>Mary
8              Minion                 5                          7              0                       Michael            4                   0              5                    3                      2                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>10>5>8                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South>Minion          3>12>10-1>7                    Jill>Fred>Frank>Michael
9              Administrator          6                          8              0                       Nigel              4                   0              1                    1                      0                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>10>6>9                       CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor East>Administrator    3>12>(vacant)>8                Jill>Fred>(vacant)>Nigel
10             Senior Manager         1                          12             0                       Fred               2                   1              1                    1                      0                     2                         1                           4                           2                             6                               3                              1>10                           CEO>Senior Manager                                  3>12                           Jill>Fred
11             Supervisor South       10                         11             0                       Wilson             3                   0              1                    1                      0                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>10>11                        CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South                 3>12>11                        Jill>Fred>Wilson
12             Supervisor West        2                          10             0                       Frank              3                   1              1                    1                      0                     2                         0                           0                           0                             2                               0                              1>2>12                         CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor West                  3>1>10                         Jill>Tom>Frank
13             Executive Mid-West     1                          NULL           NULL                    NULL               2                   0              1                    0                      1                     0                         0                           0                           0                             0                               0                              1>13                           CEO>Executive Mid-West                              3>(vacant)                     Jill>(vacant)
```

*Technical requirements*

1. The `reportsto_position_id` contains a manager's `position_id`, NULL for the top position.
2. The `position_id` must always exist, but can be vacant.
3. Managers must have a unique `position_id` (and `max_incumbents=1`) for the tree to work properly.
4. Similar positions in different sub-trees or at different levels must also have a different `position_id` to maintain the reporting structure. This is because the `reportsto_position_id` is defined for each node in the tree.
5. An `employee_id` can exist on multiple nodes, indicating than the employee has multiple jobs in the organisation. If an employee has 1 job, their `multi_job_sequence` will be `0`. If an employee has multiple jobs, their `multi_job_sequence` is incremented.
6. Positions have a `max_incumbents` to cap the amount of employees allowed to fill that position. Vacancies do not have job rows, but can be calculated.
7. Manager positions could be vacant, even if employees still report to that position.
8. If the organisation decides to restructure by adding/deleting levels or sub-trees, the SQL code should not change.
9. This example is an over-simplification. Large organisations could have more levels and options available for positions and employees (such as effective dates or a status). To reduce complexity, all employees and positions in this example are active.

**Span of Control report business requirements**

The report must answer the following questions, which are common in hierarchical organisations:

1. How many direct reports (count of employees only one level below them) does a manager have?
2. How many indirect reports (count of employees more than one level below them, all the way down to the lowest level of the tree) does a manager have?
3. How many people does this manager have "under their position" (i.e. direct reports + indirect reports)?
4. How many managers have vacant positions they need to fill in their team (vacant direct reports)?
5. How many managers have managers reporting to them who have vacancies in their teams (vacant indirect reports)?
6. What is the path from the top to each position in the tree, by name or by ID: e.g. `CEO>Senior Manager>Supervisor South>Minion`, or `1>2>5>8`?
7. What is the path from the top to each employee in the tree, by name or by ID (taking into account employees that may have multiple jobs): e.g. `Jill>Tom>Frank>Olivia` or `3>1>10-1>4`?

**Sample data**

*position* table

```
position_id  descr                            reportsto_position_id  max_incumbents
1            CEO                              NULL                   1
2            Senior Manager                   1                      1
3            West Winger                      2                      2
4            Executive Assistant              1                      1
5            Supervisor South                 10                     1
6            Supervisor East                  10                     1
7            Expert                           12                     2
8            Minion                           5                      5
9            Administrator                    6                      1
10           Senior Manager                   1                      1
11           Supervisor South                 10                     1
12           Supervisor West                  2                      1
13           Executive Mid-West               1                      1
```

*job* table

```
employee_id  multi_job_sequence  employee_name  position_id
1            0                   Tom            2
2            0                   Doug           4
3            0                   Jill           1
4            0                   Olivia         7
5            0                   Carol          8
6            0                   Mary           8
7            0                   Michael        8
8            0                   Nigel          9
9            0                   David          7
10           0                   Frank          12
10           1                   Frank          5
11           0                   Wilson         11
12           0                   Fred           10
```

**SQL**

```
-- Position incumbents. One row for each position, employee_id, multi_job_sequence combination.
with cte_incumbents
as
(
    select
    cp.position_id,
    cp.reportsto_position_id,
    cp.max_incumbents,
    cj.employee_id,
    cj.multi_job_sequence
    from position cp
    left join job cj on cj.position_id = cp.position_id
),
-- Incumbents count (filled and vacant) per position
cte_incumbents_count
as
(
    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    i.position_id,
    count(to_char(i.employee_id) || '-' || to_char(i.multi_job_sequence)) as filled_count,
    (i.max_incumbents - count(to_char(i.employee_id) || '-' || to_char(i.multi_job_sequence))) as vacant_count,
    i.max_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents i
    where i.employee_id is not null
    group by i.reportsto_position_id,
             i.position_id,
             i.max_incumbents

    UNION ALL

    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    i.position_id,
    0 as filled_count,
    (count(*) * i.max_incumbents) as vacant_count,
    i.max_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents i
    where i.employee_id is null
    group by i.reportsto_position_id,
             i.position_id,
             i.max_incumbents
),
-- Count the filled and vacant reports_to positions
cte_reportsto_count
as
(
    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    sum(i.filled_count) as filled_count,
    sum(i.vacant_count) as vacant_count,
    sum(i.max_incumbents) as total_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents_count i
    group by i.reportsto_position_id
),
-- Create the organisation tree, based on the reportsto_position_id
cte_reportsto_tree
as
(
    select
    rtt.position_id,
    rtt.employee_id,
    rtt.multi_job_sequence,
    rtt.position_descr,
    rtt.reportsto_position_id,
    rtt.employee_name,
    level as tree_level_num,
    case when connect_by_isleaf = 0 then 1 else 0 end as is_manager,
    rtt.max_incumbents,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.filled_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = rtt.position_id
    ),0) as filled_direct_reports,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.vacant_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = rtt.position_id
    ),0) as vacant_direct_reports,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(rtt.position_id,'>'),2,length(sys_connect_by_path(rtt.position_id,'>'))-1) as reporting_path_position_id,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(rtt.position_descr,'>'),2,length(sys_connect_by_path(rtt.position_descr,'>'))-1) as reporting_path_position_descr,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(nvl(case when rtt.employee_id is null then null else case when rtt.multi_job_sequence = 0 then to_char(rtt.employee_id) else rtt.employee_id || '-' || rtt.multi_job_sequence end end,'(vacant)'),'>'),2,length(sys_connect_by_path(nvl(case when rtt.employee_id is null then null else rtt.employee_id || '-' || rtt.multi_job_sequence end,'(vacant)'),'>'))-1) as reporting_path_employee,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(nvl(rtt.employee_name,'(vacant)'),'>'),2,length(sys_connect_by_path(nvl(rtt.employee_name,'(vacant)'),'>'))-1) as reporting_path_name
    from
    (
        select
        cp.position_id,
        cp.descr as position_descr,
        cp.max_incumbents,
        cp.reportsto_position_id,
        cj.employee_id,
        cj.multi_job_sequence,
        cj.employee_name
        from position cp
        left join job cj on cj.position_id = cp.position_id -- Positions may not be filled
    ) rtt
    connect by prior rtt.position_id = rtt.reportsto_position_id
    start with rtt.reportsto_position_id is null -- Start at the top of the tree
),
-- Create the report detail, traversing the tree (creating subtrees to get the indirect values). This is the tough part!
cte_report_detail
as
(
    select
    soc.position_id,
    soc.position_descr,
    soc.reportsto_position_id,
    soc.employee_id,
    soc.multi_job_sequence,
    soc.employee_name,
    soc.tree_level_num,
    soc.is_manager,
    soc.max_incumbents,
    nvl(
        (
         select
         ic.filled_count
         from cte_incumbents_count ic
         where ic.position_id = soc.position_id
        ),0) as filled_head_count,
    nvl(
        (
         select
         ic.vacant_count
         from cte_incumbents_count ic
         where ic.position_id = soc.position_id
        ),0) as vacant_head_count,
    soc.filled_direct_reports as filled_direct_reports,
    soc.vacant_direct_reports as vacant_direct_reports,
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
    -- Get the filled count of all of the positions underneath and subtract the direct reports to arrive at the filled indirect reports count
    (
        select
        sum(
             (
                select
                rtc.filled_count
                from cte_reportsto_count rtc
                where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp.position_id
             )
           )
        from position cp
        connect by prior cp.position_id = cp.reportsto_position_id
        start with cp.position_id = soc.position_id
    ) - soc.filled_direct_reports else 0 end as filled_indirect_reports,
    -- Get the vacant count of all of the positions underneath and subtract the direct reports to arrive at the vacant indirect reports count
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
    (
        select
        sum(
             (
                select
                rtc.vacant_count
                from cte_reportsto_count rtc
                where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp.position_id
             )
           )
        from position cp
        connect by prior cp.position_id = cp.reportsto_position_id
        start with cp.position_id = soc.position_id
    ) - soc.vacant_direct_reports else 0 end as vacant_indirect_reports,
    to_clob(cast(soc.reporting_path_position_id as varchar2(4000))) as reporting_path_position_id,
    to_clob(cast(soc.reporting_path_position_descr as varchar2(4000))) as reporting_path_position_descr,
    to_clob(cast(soc.reporting_path_employee as varchar2(4000))) as reporting_path_employee,
    to_clob(cast(soc.reporting_path_name as varchar2(4000))) as reporting_path_employee_name
    from cte_reportsto_tree soc
)
-- Final calculations and sort
select
r.position_id,
r.position_descr,
r.reportsto_position_id,
r.employee_id,
r.multi_job_sequence,
r.employee_name,
r.tree_level_num,
r.is_manager,
r.max_incumbents,
r.filled_head_count,
r.vacant_head_count,
r.filled_direct_reports,
r.vacant_direct_reports,
r.filled_indirect_reports,
r.vacant_indirect_reports,
(r.filled_direct_reports + r.filled_indirect_reports) as employees_under_position,
(r.vacant_direct_reports + r.vacant_indirect_reports) as vacancies_under_position,
r.reporting_path_position_id,
r.reporting_path_position_descr,
r.reporting_path_employee,
r.reporting_path_employee_name
from cte_report_detail r
order by r.position_id,
         r.employee_id,
         r.multi_job_sequence;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52637/13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of work, I managed to answer my own question to reproduce exactly the same result using CTEs.

The recursive CTEs feature works in Oracle in this situation, with a few restrictions. Another database would need to support recursion with `DEPTH FIRST` searching, along with analytical functions.
Theoretically, this code could be ported across with minor changes to the syntax.

Key points/lessons learnt:

1. The results of recursive CTEs cannot be used within another CTE, or subquery. If you want to use the results of a recursive CTE in a subquery, you must materialise in a table first.
2. You can't use a view for recursive CTEs, or you will get the error `ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here`.
3. The `SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY reportsto_position_id SET seq` clause was important to set `is_manager`, with help from the `LEAD()` analytical function.
4. Flattening a tree into the `reporting_path` fields was useful for traversing it correctly. I used the `INSTR()` function to ensure a position existed in a given path.
5. SQL Fiddle has a 8000 character limit, which forced me to materialise the other CTEs before I could run the report. That wouldn't be necessary on a normal Oracle database, as there is no limit on the query size.

**Sample data tables and basic counts**

```
-- Create a table for each current position.
create table position
(
    position_id           NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    descr                 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    reportsto_position_id NUMBER(11),
    max_incumbents        NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);

create unique index position_idx1 on position (position_id);

-- Create a table to store the current job data.
create table job
(
    employee_id        NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    multi_job_sequence NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    employee_name      VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    position_id        NUMBER(11) NOT NULL
);

create unique index job_idx1 on job (employee_id, multi_job_sequence);
create index job_idx2 on job (position_id, employee_id, multi_job_sequence);

-- Insert data into position table
insert into position values (1, 'CEO', NULL, 1);
insert into position values (2, 'Senior Manager', 1, 1);
insert into position values (3, 'West Winger', 2, 2);
insert into position values (4, 'Executive Assistant', 1, 1);
insert into position values (5, 'Supervisor South', 10, 1);
insert into position values (6, 'Supervisor East', 10, 1);
insert into position values (7, 'Expert', 12, 2);
insert into position values (8, 'Minion', 5, 5);
insert into position values (9, 'Administrator', 6, 1);
insert into position values (10, 'Senior Manager', 1, 1);
insert into position values (11, 'Supervisor South', 10, 1);
insert into position values (12, 'Supervisor West', 2, 1);
insert into position values (13, 'Executive Mid-West', 1, 1);

commit;

-- Insert data into job table
insert into job values (1, 0, 'Tom', 2);
insert into job values (2, 0, 'Doug', 4);
insert into job values (3, 0, 'Jill', 1);
insert into job values (4, 0, 'Olivia', 7);
insert into job values (5, 0, 'Carol', 8);
insert into job values (6, 0, 'Mary', 8);
insert into job values (7, 0, 'Michael', 8);
insert into job values (8, 0, 'Nigel', 9);
insert into job values (9, 0, 'David', 7);
insert into job values (10, 0, 'Frank', 12);
insert into job values (10, 1, 'Frank', 5);
insert into job values (11, 0, 'Wilson', 11);
insert into job values (12, 0, 'Fred', 10);

commit;

-- Build up the tables

-- Position incumbents. One row for each position, employee_id, multi_job_sequence combination.
create table cte_incumbents
as
(
    select
    cp.position_id,
    cp.reportsto_position_id,
    cp.max_incumbents,
    cj.employee_id,
    cj.multi_job_sequence
    from position cp
    left join job cj on cj.position_id = cp.position_id
);

create unique index cte_incumbents_idx1 on cte_incumbents (position_id, employee_id, multi_job_sequence);
create index cte_incumbents_idx2 on cte_incumbents (position_id, reportsto_position_id);

-- Incumbents count (filled and vacant) per position
create table cte_incumbents_count
as
(
    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    i.position_id,
    count(to_char(i.employee_id) || '-' || to_char(i.multi_job_sequence)) as filled_count,
    (i.max_incumbents - count(to_char(i.employee_id) || '-' || to_char(i.multi_job_sequence))) as vacant_count,
    i.max_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents i
    where i.employee_id is not null
    group by i.reportsto_position_id,
             i.position_id,
             i.max_incumbents

    UNION ALL

    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    i.position_id,
    0 as filled_count,
    (count(*) * i.max_incumbents) as vacant_count,
    i.max_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents i
    where i.employee_id is null
    group by i.reportsto_position_id,
             i.position_id,
             i.max_incumbents
);

create unique index cte_incumbents_count_idx on cte_incumbents_count (reportsto_position_id, position_id);


-- Count the filled and vacant reports_to positions
create table cte_reportsto_count
as
(
    select
    i.reportsto_position_id,
    sum(i.filled_count) as filled_count,
    sum(i.vacant_count) as vacant_count,
    sum(i.max_incumbents) as total_incumbents
    from cte_incumbents_count i
    group by i.reportsto_position_id
);

create unique index cte_reportsto_count_idx on cte_reportsto_count (reportsto_position_id);
```

**Report using CTEs**

```
create table cte_reportsto_tree as
-- Create the organisation tree, based on the reportsto_position_id
with cte_reportsto_tree_base (
                                 position_id,
                                 position_descr,
                                 reportsto_position_id,
                                 employee_id,
                                 multi_job_sequence,
                                 employee_name,
                                 tree_level_num,
                                 max_incumbents,
                                 filled_direct_reports,
                                 vacant_direct_reports,
                                 reporting_path_position_id,
                                 reporting_path_position_descr,
                                 reporting_path_employee,
                                 reporting_path_employee_name
                             )
as
(
    -- Anchor member
    select
    cp1.position_id,
    cp1.descr as position_descr,
    cp1.reportsto_position_id,
    cj1.employee_id,
    cj1.multi_job_sequence,
    cj1.employee_name,
    1 as tree_level_num,
    cp1.max_incumbents,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.filled_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp1.position_id
    ),0) as filled_direct_reports,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.vacant_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp1.position_id
    ),0) as vacant_direct_reports,
    to_char(cp1.position_id) as reporting_path_position_id,
    cp1.descr as reporting_path_position_descr,
    to_char(cj1.employee_id) as reporting_path_employee,
    cj1.employee_name as reporting_path_employee_name
    from position cp1
    left join job cj1 on cj1.position_id = cp1.position_id -- Positions may not be filled
    where cp1.position_id = 1 -- start at position = 1

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member
    select
    cp2.position_id,
    cp2.descr as position_descr,
    cp2.reportsto_position_id,
    cj2.employee_id,
    cj2.multi_job_sequence,
    cj2.employee_name,
    rtt.tree_level_num + 1 as tree_level_num,
    cp2.max_incumbents,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.filled_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp2.position_id
    ),0) as filled_direct_reports,
    nvl((
        select
        rtc.vacant_count
        from cte_reportsto_count rtc
        where rtc.reportsto_position_id = cp2.position_id
    ),0) as vacant_direct_reports,
    rtt.reporting_path_position_id || '>' || to_char(cp2.position_id) as reporting_path_position_id,
    rtt.reporting_path_position_descr || '>' || cp2.descr as reporting_path_position_descr,
    rtt.reporting_path_employee || '>' || nvl(case when cj2.employee_id is null then null else case when cj2.multi_job_sequence = 0 then to_char(cj2.employee_id) else to_char(cj2.employee_id) || '-' || to_char(cj2.multi_job_sequence) end end,'(vacant)') as reporting_path_employee,
    rtt.reporting_path_employee_name || '>' || nvl(cj2.employee_name,'(vacant)') as reporting_path_employee_name
    from position cp2
    inner join cte_reportsto_tree_base rtt on rtt.position_id = cp2.reportsto_position_id
    left join job cj2 on cj2.position_id = cp2.position_id -- Positions may not be filled
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY reportsto_position_id SET seq
select
rtt.position_id,
rtt.position_descr,
rtt.reportsto_position_id,
rtt.employee_id,
rtt.multi_job_sequence,
rtt.employee_name,
rtt.tree_level_num,
rtt.max_incumbents,
rtt.filled_direct_reports,
rtt.vacant_direct_reports,
rtt.reporting_path_position_id,
rtt.reporting_path_position_descr,
rtt.reporting_path_employee,
rtt.reporting_path_employee_name,
case when (rtt.tree_level_num - lead(rtt.tree_level_num) over (order by seq)) < 0 then 1 else 0 end is_manager -- Is a manager if there is a difference between levels on the tree.
from cte_reportsto_tree_base rtt;

create index cte_reportsto_tree_idx on cte_reportsto_tree (position_id, reportsto_position_id, employee_id, multi_job_sequence);

create table cte_fir as
(
    select
    soc.position_id,
    soc.is_manager,
    soc.tree_level_num,
    soc.filled_direct_reports,
    soc.vacant_direct_reports,
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
        nvl((
            select
            sum(ind.filled_direct_reports)
            from cte_reportsto_tree ind
            where ind.tree_level_num > soc.tree_level_num -- Must be at a lower level
        ),0)
    else 0 end as filled_indirect_reports,
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
        nvl((
            select
            sum(ind.vacant_direct_reports)
            from cte_reportsto_tree ind
            where ind.tree_level_num > soc.tree_level_num -- Must be at a lower level
        ),0)
    else 0 end as vacant_indirect_reports
    from cte_reportsto_tree soc
    where soc.tree_level_num = 1

    UNION ALL

    select
    soc.position_id,
    soc.is_manager,
    soc.tree_level_num,
    soc.filled_direct_reports,
    soc.vacant_direct_reports,
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
        nvl((
            select
            sum(ind.filled_direct_reports)
            from cte_reportsto_tree ind
            where ind.tree_level_num > soc.tree_level_num -- Must be at a lower level
            and instr(ind.reporting_path_position_id, '>'|| soc.position_id || '>') > 0 -- The position must be in the flattened tree path (quick way of traversing the tree)
        ),0)
    else 0 end as filled_indirect_reports,
    case when soc.is_manager = 1 then
        nvl((
            select
            sum(ind.vacant_direct_reports)
            from cte_reportsto_tree ind
            where ind.tree_level_num > soc.tree_level_num -- Must be at a lower level
            and instr(ind.reporting_path_position_id, '>'|| soc.position_id ||'>') > 0 -- The position must be in the flattened tree path (quick way of traversing the tree)
        ),0)
    else 0 end as vacant_indirect_reports
    from cte_reportsto_tree soc
    where soc.tree_level_num > 1
);

create index cte_fir_idx on cte_fir (position_id);

select
soc.position_id,
soc.position_descr,
soc.reportsto_position_id,
soc.employee_id,
soc.multi_job_sequence,
soc.employee_name,
soc.tree_level_num,
soc.is_manager,
soc.max_incumbents,
nvl(
    (
        select
        ic.filled_count
        from cte_incumbents_count ic
        where ic.position_id = soc.position_id
    ),0) as filled_head_count,
nvl(
    (
        select
        ic.vacant_count
        from cte_incumbents_count ic
        where ic.position_id = soc.position_id
    ),0) as vacant_head_count,
soc.filled_direct_reports as filled_direct_reports,
soc.vacant_direct_reports as vacant_direct_reports,
(
    select
    sum(fir.filled_indirect_reports)
    from cte_fir fir
    where fir.position_id = soc.position_id
) as filled_indirect_reports,
(
    select
    sum(fir.vacant_indirect_reports)
    from cte_fir fir
    where fir.position_id = soc.position_id
) as vacant_indirect_reports,
(
    select
    sum(fir.filled_indirect_reports)
    from cte_fir fir
    where fir.position_id = soc.position_id
) + soc.filled_direct_reports as employees_under_position,
(
    select
    sum(fir.vacant_indirect_reports)
    from cte_fir fir
    where fir.position_id = soc.position_id
) + soc.vacant_direct_reports as vacancies_under_position,
soc.reporting_path_position_id,
soc.reporting_path_position_descr,
soc.reporting_path_employee,
soc.reporting_path_employee_name
from cte_reportsto_tree soc
order by soc.position_id,
         soc.employee_id,
         soc.multi_job_sequence;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80d82/449)

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is yes.

Standard SQL:1999 defines "Recursive CTEs" (Recursive Common Table Expressions) that do the job of a `CONNECT BY` and much more. They are designed to walk any kind of graph -- hierarchies being a subset of what they can process.

Your query is quite extensive so I don't have the time to go over it and rewrite it in standard SQL.

You ask for which databases can do it. Well, they are currently implemented by:

- Oracle.
- DB2. Does not implement cycle detection in Linux/Unix/Windows. It does in z/OS.
- PostgreSQL.
- SQL Server (since 2012?). Does not implement cycle detection.
- MariaDB, since 10.2. Does not implement cycle detection.
- MySQL since 8.0. Does not implement cycle detection.
- H2 (since 1.4?). Does not implement cycle detection.
- HyperSQL.
- other databases...

If you provide a smaller example I would be quite interested on rephrasing it using a recursive CTE.

For example, the following recursive CTE (in Oracle) will find all the sub-tree of employees who report (directly and indirectly) to position = 2:

```
with
x (position_id, descr, reportsto_position_id, max_incumbents, cur_level) as (
  select
    position_id, descr, reportsto_position_id, max_incumbents,
    1
    from position
    where position_id = 2 -- start at position = 2
  union all
  select
    p.position_id, p.descr, p.reportsto_position_id, p.max_incumbents,
    x.cur_level + 1
    from position p
    join x on p.reportsto_position_id = x.position_id
)
select * from x;
```

Comment: As much as I would like to simplify this question further, I've learnt from testing that I needed at least 4 levels in the tree to demonstrate that the algorithm works. We must answer ALL of the question to be confident - that is the challenge. I too have heard and read that it is *possible* to use recursive CTEs, but I've not seen ANSI-SQL that produces anything similar (on the internet or at work).

Comment: The example I posted is a recursive CTE that walks the tree "downwards", in multiple levels (not just two) and will return 6 nodes. You can walk up, sideways, etc. I have successfully used recursive CTEs to do all a CONNECT BY can do and much more. I have no doubt that it is possible to do it. Unfortunately your example is [necessarily] long, and maybe not suitable for great answers at stackoverflow. If you break it down into smaller questions, I'm sure a lot of people will answer them one by one. At this point I'm afraid it will fall into the category "TL;DR;" for most of the readers.

Comment: I've removed the additional example section and moved the expected output to near the top for the TL:DR people.

Comment: I couldn't get your answer to run in SQL Fiddle (Oracle 11gR2).

Comment: @bruceskyaus I think support for recursive CTEs was introduced in Oracle 12.1 [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) supports Oracle 18, so you could try it there

Comment: @bruceskyaus I fixed it. `LEVEL` is a reserved word so i replaced it with `CUR_LEVEL`. I tested in Oracle 12c1 and runs well.

Comment: Also, I think you'll probably need to start a bounty for this one at some point. Just a suggestion.